# ASP.NET CORE 5.0 Identity Display current logged in user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am try to display in `Index Page` which user submite `ticket`. In my Model I add property

```
 public int? UserId { get; set; }

 public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

And In controller I have something like

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

SO far I try to add something like this

```
var userEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser.Name = userEmail;
```

Here is problem that I get error message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So my question is, How can I assigne in IndexPage after user is logged in and submit ticket I need to display his/her username or email address.

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is null there? Do you try to take a look in the userEmail Object? Is it null or has it values?

Comment: Yes, I debug and `ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser.Name` throw error

Comment: var username get correct email but in `ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser.Name` throw error message

Comment: Ok than your Applicationuser ist null in your Model. You can change the ApplicationUser to a string to store the name or email. or you have to create a new ApplicationUser in your model to fill the name

Comment: @OliverDzaeck I have alredy have ApplicationUser model. I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that ApplicationUser is **NULL**. So when you try to access the Name property, it throws that error. You could just do something like this **assuming** its an **existing** user:

`ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userEmail);`

You could also use the UserManager built in class which has a FindByEmail() method as well. But the point is, FIRST grab the ApplicationUser from the DB using the userEmail. If its a new user, then you need to create a new ApplicationUser in order to access the Name property.

Comment: How can I get this `userEmail` ?

Comment: Dont you already have it using this code? var userEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

Comment: I use RepositoryPatten and when I write something I get error message
`ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _unitOfwork.ApplicationUser.Get(u => u.Email == userEmail);`

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.ApplicationUser>' to 'ProjectName.Models.ApplicationUser'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: I get the point. But I get encrypter UserEmail which is not solution for me. Since I add `ApplicationUser` and I want to display `Name`

Comment: Not sure why your Get returns an IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> instead of just a ApplicationUser. That why you are seeing that "Cannot implicitly convert" error. I would need to see your code but usually you have methods in your repository like so:

Get -> returns an ApplicationUser,
GetAll -> returns a list of ApplicationUser,
etc..

join here so I can try to help further: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229531/asp-net-core-mvc-temp

Comment: When you will be online just pm me :) I have a couple of error